# Why is there such difference in the App size on Android and iOS Apps that are build on Unity?

Tags: c#, android, ios, xcode, unity-game-engine

I have uploaded Apps on both Play Store and Apple App Store and found out that the apps have huge size difference on both the platforms.
The App size on Play Store was 105MB but the same app on iOS was of 251 MB.
I am building the IPA for upload on XCode.

Comment: Try [this.](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/iphone-playerSizeOptimization.html) In addition to checking the texture compression method, also check the Build Compression setting in Build Settings.

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 different sizes to be compared: **Build** Size, **Download** Size & **Install** Size.

- An iOS App Store Page shows the **install size** of an app, not the download size.
- The Google Play Store Page shows the **install** and **download size**, which are equal on Android.

The **Build Size** is big, because it contains all assets, all code binaries & debug symbols for for different devices (e.g. armv7, arm64, ...).

The **Download Size** is what the user will download over the network.

- Each Target Device can have different download sizes.
- In the Google Play Console the download size can be found **App Bundle explorer**.
- On App Store Connect the iOS download size can be found under TestFlight > Builds > iOS > Build > Build Metadata > Compressed File Size > **App Store File Sizes**

The **Install Size** is the disk space the app takes on the users device.

- On Android it is the same as the Download Size, it is unzipped in memory, when the app is started.
- On iOS the downloaded IPA is unpacked and bigger then the download size.

Here is an **example** on an unity app that is just uploaded

- iOS Build Size: 482 MB
- iOS Download Size for iPad Air 2: 374 MB
- iOS Install Size for iPad Air 2: 645 MB
- Android AAB Build Size: 424 MB
- Android APK Download & Install Size: 416 MB
- Note: If I unzip the APK on my computer the size is 742 MB.